# The 'Date modified' column in Programs and Features window is empty

Tags: windows, installation, windows-8.1

I am definitely sure; I was able to sort installed applications by install date-time.

But now the only column is *Date modified*, and it is empty.

[image]

How do I fill this column?

Answer (score 7):

Right-click the row with the headings on it, select "More...", and then deselect "Date Modified". Right-click the row again, select "More..." and select "Installed On"

Comment: It worked, but this seems to be a bug of Windows, as I do not remember changing the columns. Probably some File Explorer settings were wrongly applied automatically to this. I can't believe that Microsoft has not done anything to fix this and this still happens 5 years later.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue select Tools | Folder Options from the menu. Then click the Restore Defaults button in the lower right corner.

All the columns with data should re-appear.

I've had this happen a few times, not sure what's causing it, but this fixes the issue.